# What is wrong with this makefile function?

Tags: makefile

I am not proficient at makefiles. I have RTFM and looked on SO, but I still don't get what I'm doing wrong in this simple example.

This **works**:

```
    TARGET = nim
    ifeq ($(CONFIG),Release)
      $(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(TARGET)_unstripped,$(APP_SOURCES) Neonim.cc,$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
      $(eval $(call STRIP_RULE,$(TARGET),$(TARGET)_unstripped))
    else
      $(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(TARGET),$(APP_SOURCES) Neonim.cc,$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
    endif
    $(eval $(call NMF_RULE,$(TARGET),))

    TARGET = ttt
    ifeq ($(CONFIG),Release)
      $(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(TARGET)_unstripped,$(APP_SOURCES) TTToe3D.cc,$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
      $(eval $(call STRIP_RULE,$(TARGET),$(TARGET)_unstripped))
    else
      $(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(TARGET),$(APP_SOURCES) TTToe3D.cc,$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
    endif
    $(eval $(call NMF_RULE,$(TARGET),))
```

This **doesn't work**:

```
    define bld =
      SOURCES = $(APP_SOURCES) $(2)
      ifeq ($(CONFIG),Release)
        $(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(1)_unstripped,$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
        $(eval $(call STRIP_RULE,$(1),$(1)_unstripped))
      else
        $(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(1),$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
      endif
      $(eval $(call NMF_RULE,$(1),))
    endef
    $(eval $(call bld,nim,Neonim.cc))
    $(eval $(call bld,ttt,TTToe3D.cc))
```

Are they not equivalent? How do I write this function?

Comment: First, which version of GNU make are you using?  And second, what do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What happens?

Comment: On each line where you use 'eval' add the exact same line with 'info' instead of 'eval'. This will display exactly how the eval function is expanding. Maybe something doesn't expand as expected ? My guess is that some '$' chars should be doubled into the define because they are escaped in the eval function. If this is your problem, you will see it with the 'info' function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given us enough information to reproduce the error (and I really don't think your example is [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but I'll go out on a limb. Change this:

```
define bld =
  SOURCES = $(APP_SOURCES) $(2)
  ifeq ($(CONFIG),Release)
    $(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(1)_unstripped,$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
    $(eval $(call STRIP_RULE,$(1),$(1)_unstripped))
  else
    $(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(1),$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
  endif
  $(eval $(call NMF_RULE,$(1),))
endef
```

to this:

```
define bld
  SOURCES = $(APP_SOURCES) $(2)
  ifeq ($(CONFIG),Release)
    $(call LINK_RULE,$(1)_unstripped,$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS))
    $(call STRIP_RULE,$(1),$(1)_unstripped)
  else
    $(call LINK_RULE,$(1),$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS))
  endif
  $(call NMF_RULE,$(1),)
endef
```

Comment: The limb almost held - I took out the line SOURCES = $(APP_SOURCES) $(2), and just used that value in the parameter list - then this solution worked!